# What is an easy to adapt alternative to multidict for Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

Title says it all.

I'm trying to run an adaptation to [this code](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/master/examples/frequency.py) from a virtualenv that doesn't support Python 3 and, [as multidict doesn't support Python 2](https://github.com/aio-libs/multidict/issues/4#issuecomment-231101264), I'd like to consider alternatives to this module which could work with Python 2 before considering changing my host.

The key part of the code which uses multidict functionalities is the following:

```
def getFrequencyDictForText(sentence):
    fullTermsDict = multidict.MultiDict()
    tmpDict = {}

    # making dict for counting frequencies
    for text in sentence.split(" "):
        if re.match("a|the|an|the|to|in|for|of|or|by|with|is|on|that|be", text):
            continue
        val = tmpDict.get(text, 0)
        tmpDict[text.lower()] = val + 1
    for key in tmpDict:
        fullTermsDict.add(key, tmpDict[key])
    return fullTermsDict
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Exactly, @Carcigenicate. That's a good approach I was ignoring in order to find some sort of proper way to do that with a similar module, but that'll have to be the case if I can't find it.

Comment: `tmpDict` is a regular dict (so the keys form a set), which means `fullTermsDict` could be a regular dict as well; you never try to add the same key to it twice. Really all you need is an instance of `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) with defaulting list values can be used to get a close approximation:

```
# Each new value is created by calling the "list" function
# Saves you from needing to do a "if key not in fullTermsDict" check prior to "append"ing
fullTermsDict = defaultdict(list)  

. . .

fullTermsDict[key].append(tmpDict[key])
```

---

Obligatory side note: Python prefers snake_case, not camelCase.

Comment: Good point once again. I'm adapting this code to the conventions in my end while modifying it, but I'm still learning so I don't feel comfortable to send a pull request, for instance. Anyway, thank you very much for the lights you brought to this topic!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a full-blown multidict; you just need a `Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter

def get_frequency_dict_for_text(sentence):
    skip_words = {"a", "the", "an", ...}

    words = (x.lower() for x in sentence.split(" ") if x not in skip_words)
    return Counter(words)
```